# Is there a public DNS site that serves private addresses, or is there a better reliable option?

Tags: networking, dns, dd-wrt

I have a private home network served by dual private DNS servers at this time.  The Internet router currently serves DHCP along with the required DNS addresses.  However, this entire network is very dynamic in that I am always making changes to it.  I am pretty much over trying to have my own DNS servers always on as I try various changes to my systems.

I used to have my servers provide both DNS and DHCP, but the impact of my changes was too painful.  If DHCP is down, it's unreasonably difficult to access the network at all.  So, I moved DHCP to my routers.  I've decided that I similarly need to get my primary DNS off of my systems and only inject it when I am actually trying something new there.

My Linksys routers don't natively provide an internal DNS server.  I see that DD-WRT does that through DNSMasq, or so it seems though I haven't tried that.  But, I've put up DD-WRT before and I'd just rather not do that as my primary option.  It does seem to be an option, however.

I use DynDNS so that I can access my network remotely.  I looked at the services they provide and, honestly, their explanations are as clear as mud.  I'm sure they make sense once you know them, but I cannot understand their documentation well enough to know exactly what services they offer.  It's written for those that already know it, not for those trying to discover it.  It's the poorest part of their service offerings.

So, I come to my question.  Is there an external service that I can use as a private DNS server for my internal network?  I assume it would also be my primary Internet DNS provider.  But, my private network has a domain and private addresses in the 10.x.x.x range.  I'd want to be able to register my private A records, as well as others, either statically or dynamically and serve them on request only to my systems.  IDK if that is done or even makes sense.  But, it seems like a reasonable enough service to me on its face.

Thanks...

Comment: Googling for "dns hosting service" produces lots of hits. What are you looking for from Superuser?

Comment: Those services are for public addresses.  That is not what I requested.

Comment: What's wrong with running a recursive DNS locally? You can have something like bind up and running in an hour if you read an online guide or two...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go the DNSMasq route, it seems to do what you need. You set the DHCP static reservation, and DNSMasq does the DNS "Server" (I think DNSMasq is more of a DNS intercept, but the end result is the same),

Yes, this means DD-WRT which you don't want, but IMHO it's much better than Linksys firmware (I've been bit by bugs in the firmware). It's a tool that does what you want, and has fewer bugs that plague your current setup.

An "external, yet private DNS server" is more difficult than you think. Remember that DNS requests are UDP, so they're easily spoofable. You seem to have this data that you want to be just your network, but you want it outside of your network where others can access it. Reverse lookups would be odd too.  How can you go from 10.0.0.2 => yourhost.yourspecificdomain on the big ol' Internet?

So, the best routes I can see seem to be things you already have discounted - either a local DNS server, or use the DNSMasq tools in DD-WRT.